# Telerik Media Player

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm trying to set the Telerik Media player to start at a certain time. 
So for example if a user inputs 10:00 and the clip will play at 10:00

There's limited documentation on the Media Player, but I found a method called "StartTime" and when I set the clip it'll do a postback but it won't start at the inputted time.

```js
protected void RadTime_ItemSelected(object sender, DropDownListEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaPlayer.StartTime = double.Parse("10.00");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the telerik community this is absolutely the correct way to accomplish this task I was attempting.